# Which Visual Studio project should I use for CRUD programming in .NET Core 6/7?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, crud

When I use MAUI, I don't want to have the database on the device (desktop PC, cell phone or tablet) but rather on my server. The good alternative option is a service (CRUD). My idea is that I then write an ASP.NET server application that allows any MAUI frontend to communicate with database on the server.

I've read a lot about it, but I don't know what the current status is in .NET Core 6 or 7? Earlier web application project is specified in tutorials, but now Web API. I assume that it is the same, right?

Or are there other (better) ways to implement communication between a MAUI native client and server database?

Thanks
pcsasa

Answer (score 3):

> I assume that it is the same, right?

Yes, the `Web API` is appropriate for your project

Actually, you can separate your projects into two types. `Backend` and `Frontend`. it enables you to use your `Web API` to feed other types of `frontend` projects like `WebSite`

Comment: Thanks Hamid. That's what I want, to create an interface to the database. Then it doesn't matter if I access it from a MAUI native (desktop app or cell phone) or from Blazor Server, and I don't need a database on the target device anymore! One other question: What about authentication? I read about JWT Authentication, is this the right way?

Comment: @pcsasa the authentication process is part of your backend project. there are some ways to apply authentication and one of them is JWT authentication. it is straightforward and easy to learn and implement

Comment: the question of authentication was related to CRUD service. I cannot have the interface open, otherwise anyone who knows the addresses can send a query to my database.

Comment: Database security is separate from your project. you should protect the database through its authentication process. on the other hand, you have to protect the `action` of each `controller` in your Web API by the Identity process that is provided by Jwt authentication. the Web API user (client app) has to get a `token` from your API through the authentication process and then use that `token` to access other actions by passing it as a bearer token in the header of the request

Answer (score 0):

In the time between I found out that there are some updates. Basically, since NET 6 there are "Minimal APIs" and that is a bit different from what you know so far. Between NET 6 and NET 7 there are then some crucial differences in "Minimal APIs" (especially regarding filters). But you don't find much about this and I'm currently implementing the findings in a project (let's see if I succeed).

Authentication and authorization can, as I initially also thinking, best be implemented via JWT, but beware also here there are differences between NET 6 and NET 7 (please see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-7-preview-5/ ).

The only thing I haven't figured out yet is how to implement 2FA with JWT, but I haven't looked for it for long either. If someone here knows, can he please post.